# Is it acceptable to refer a variable to itself?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

E.g.

```
    blob_info = upload_files[0]
    blob_info = blob_info.key()
```

Or would it be better to do

```
    blob_info = (upload_files[0]).key()
```

I prefer splitting things up to make them more readable

Comment: Why the extra set of parentheses? Note that this is a *style* question and matters of style are generally not suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: The question is more about readabilty @phant0m

Comment: Since there is no context as to where any of these variables are used, it seems silly to unpack them all into separate variables, defeating the point of object oriented design.

Comment: @peterretief Exactly, and that is subjective.

Comment: @phant0m i would say the line between objectivity and subjectivity is fluid, convention becomes method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
blob_info = upload_files[0]
blob_key = blob_info.key()
```

Makes more sense to me. Or event better, just refer to `blob_info.key()` whenever it's needed.

Comment: thanks that would probably be best "when needed